# rpmbuild: How can I 'Require' one package *or* another

Tags: centos, rpm

So, I'm trying to fix a spec file right now for rpmbuild.

On Suse, it looks like the X11 library development package is named "xorg-x11-libX11-devel" while on CentOS it seems to be named "libX11-devel". In an ideal universe, I could just use some magical binary operator to require one or the other. Something like:

```
BuildRequires:  xorg-x11-libX11-devel || libX11-devel
```

Does something like that exist, or do I need to script some sort of zainy thing to get this to work?

Comment: Is there a specific header file, e.g. `/usr/include/X11/X11.h`, that you can require instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to use a conditional for this.

```
%if 0%{?suse_version}      # any version of SuSE
BuildRequires: libX11-devel
%else
BuildRequires: xorg-x11-libX11-devel
%endif
```

Further information can be found from [OpenSUSE](http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE%3aBuild_Service_cross_distribution_howto) and [Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging%3aDistTag) wikis respectively.